# Single Logout Identity Server3 for multiple MVC applications with OpenId owin katana middleware

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, owin, logout, identityserver3

I have implemented IdentityServer3 to create my own identity server which is hosted on azure cloud.
I have couple of client applications that gets authenticated via my identity server. Both these applications are MVC applications. One of them is running on Azure as cloudapp and other one is on my local machine and run it on localhost. As expected, when I login to one of them, I gets logeed in to other one automatically. **But, when I log-out of any one of them, I don't get logout automatically from other one opened in the same browser.**

Any help would greatly be appreciated...:)

Below is auth configuration of my client apps

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = ConfigHelper.GetAppSetting(ConfigConstants.ClientIdKeyName),
            Authority = ConfigHelper.GetAppSetting(ConfigConstants.IdpUriKeyName),
            RedirectUri = "https://myclient1.cloudapp.net/",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://myclient1.cloudapp.net/account/logoutcallback",
            ResponseType = "code id_token token",
            Scope = "openid profile address roles email",

            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role"
            },

            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                {
                    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(
                        "https://myidp.cloudapp.net/core/connect/token",
                        "myclient-1",
                        "myclient-1-secret");

                    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                        n.Code, n.RedirectUri);

                    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
                    }

                    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "name", "role"),
                    n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                }
            }
        };

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
    }
```

I am calling

```
this.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
```

to logout off identity server

When it comes back to my client application, it comes to

```
    public ActionResult LogoutCallback()
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("SecureCookieName");
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        cookie.Expires = new DateTime(1999, 10, 12);
        Response.Cookies.Remove("SecureCookieName");
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        SessionManager.KillSession();  //Custom stuff to clear the session of client application.
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: What does your IdentityServer3 client configuration look like? Specifically, what LogoutUri values are set for your clients?

Comment: Sorry.. my bad.. i forgot to replace my constants with actual values. I have updated the post. Please have a look at it again. Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving it:

Create a property on eacheach client nammed logout endpoint, or have a convention that each client should have a  `/account/logout/` route.

Then, implement this route in each app, and make that route delete the app cookie. At the `logout.html` view in idsrv, create a javascript that loops thru a list of all clients and call this endpoints for each.

Comment: Thanks for the idea John. Looping through all the client's logout end-point do make sense if we have only a handful of clients. If the list grows, then it is not a feasible idea. In my case, I am gonna have more than 20 client applications.

Comment: Right, well that's up to you. Here's the doc stating it. 

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/signout-http.html